# Google Desktop or Indexed Text File Search Within ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, search, indexing, full-text-search

I have a folder with thousands of text files and I'd like to paste and search content into a web form and return matches in those files.

Is there a way to do content indexing of those files and do these searches from within an ASP.NET application?

What tools and techniques are available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With text (or other) files and open source you can use **Lucene**.

http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net

Lucene has .NET/C# ports.

> "Google Desktop has made a splash by bringing this functionality to end users. Now you have the power to bring the same indexing and searching capabilities into your applications using Lucene.Net, a high-performance, scalable search engine library written in the C# language and utilizing the .NET Framework."

**Working with Lucene**

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/BrainDump/Working-with-Lucene-dot-Net/

**SO threads**

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=lucene.net

Comment: I'm deleting my answer because yours has more information, but a better URL is http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/ - just http://www.lucene.net goes to the Java version.

Comment: did you get any full source code sample using ***Lucene.Net*** and **ASP.NET** ?